# view query empty when only using 1 or 2 characters in couchDB/Php

Tags: php, couchbase

Using the php couchbase sdk, and i've got a view which indexes various object types.

hitting the view directly returns results no problem

```
http://127.0.0.1:8092/default/_design/dev_domain/_view/search?stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&limit=10&skip=0&startkey=%22S%22&endkey=%22S\u02ad%22
```

Which returns happily

```
{"total_rows":700,"rows":[
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\b63008d6d65df09a6947a9c3ebb9f3137ed3c54ac3754a21ba2098d80537c3ef","key":"sam","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\f6b4119f7373edb6cfc7901702a2bb81b655834cd009cdfcaaafbaa1991f2cc4","key":"sam","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\b63008d6d65df09a6947a9c3ebb9f3137ed3c54ac3754a21ba2098d80537c3ef","key":"samp","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\f6b4119f7373edb6cfc7901702a2bb81b655834cd009cdfcaaafbaa1991f2cc4","key":"samp","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\b63008d6d65df09a6947a9c3ebb9f3137ed3c54ac3754a21ba2098d80537c3ef","key":"sampl","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\f6b4119f7373edb6cfc7901702a2bb81b655834cd009cdfcaaafbaa1991f2cc4","key":"sampl","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\b63008d6d65df09a6947a9c3ebb9f3137ed3c54ac3754a21ba2098d80537c3ef","key":"sample","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\f6b4119f7373edb6cfc7901702a2bb81b655834cd009cdfcaaafbaa1991f2cc4","key":"sample","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\b63008d6d65df09a6947a9c3ebb9f3137ed3c54ac3754a21ba2098d80537c3ef","key":"sampled","value":"SampleData"},
{"id":"TestCompany\\Model\\SampleObject\\f6b4119f7373edb6cfc7901702a2bb81b655834cd009cdfcaaafbaa1991f2cc4","key":"sampled","value":"SampleData"}
]
}
```

But using the php sdk:

```
$test = $cb->view("dev_domain", "search",array("startkey"=>"s","endkey"=>"s"."\u02ad"));
```

return no results, using 3 or more keys is fine, ie:

```
$test = $cb->view("dev_domain", "search",array("startkey"=>"sam","endkey"=>"sam"."\u02ad"));


Array

(

[total_rows] => 700

[rows] => Array

(

[0] => Array

(

[id] => Authentic\Model\SampleObject\b63008d6d65df09a6947a9c3ebb9f3137ed3c54ac3754a21ba2098d80537c3ef

[key] => sam

[value] => SampleData

)



[1] => Array

(

[id] => Authentic\Model\SampleObject\f6b4119f7373edb6cfc7901702a2bb81b655834cd009cdfcaaafbaa1991f2cc4

[key] => sam

[value] => SampleData

)


)



)
```

I can't figure out how to pipe the sdk through charles (proxy) so not having any luck debugging that..

Comment: what api are you using to connect?

Comment: Note that using three characters (the `'sam'` option) does **not** work because it only returns the two results that have precisely that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at the end of the day, of course my data was only indexed at 3 characters and over (as shown in the sample) , so my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `\u02ad` is already JSON encoded, and so when you provide that to the CouchDB SDK in PHP it's going to get re-encoded (probably to `\\u02ad` which won't result in what you want by the time it gets to CouchDB itself).

You should either include the literal Unicode character in your string, or wrap your unicode string in a `json_decode` wrapper so that it's decoded before being passed into the SDK method, eg:

```
"endkey"=>"s".json_decode('"\u02ad"')
```

Note the single quotes around the double quoted sequence.